Как var переменную инициализировать выборным типом?
int? value = null;
var user = value ?? "Не введено";
Console.WriteLine(user);

Не могу додумать как реализовать:
Создаётся неявно типизированная переменная и инициализируется типом в зависимости от значения другой переменной. Если value null то переменная String, если какое то целочисленое значение, то станет int.
Выдаёт ошибку. Но не могу понять где нужно явно привести к типу.
Оператор "??" невозможно применить к операнду типа "int?" и "string".

Если вас такому учат, то советую задуматься, ибо это ужасный код, ужасное решение. Если всеж нужно решение, то наверно, так: object user = value is not null ? value : "Не введено";. Если нужен var, то одну из сторон скастуйте в object ((object) value например).

var это не тип. string user = value.HasValue ? $"{value}" "Не введено"; или так var user = value?.ToString() ?? "Не введено";

Это все проблема ключевого слова var, так же как и auto c++, объяснение одно, его нужно использовать когда нет необходимости явного вывода одного типа на момент появления переменной, это не тип, а ключевое слово, читайте подробнее в документации. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables не используйте его пока не поймёте для чего он существует. Если вас учат его использовать как любой тип, то перестаньте учиться по данным представлеными каким либо источником. Учите сначала старые версии языка.

Я вижу три альтернативы:

Использовать общий тип (в данном случае object) и паттерн-матчинг (сопоставление с образцом).
Сделать класс принимающий несколько типов (int, string) или иерархию классов на каждый тип (ООП на всю катушку).
Перейти на язык, в котором есть discriminated union (размеченное объединение), например, F#. В C# это можно неуклюже реализовать на классах. См. например, библиотеку OneOf. См. также монады Either, Maybe.

Да, много страшных незнакомых слов, но информация по ним легко ищется с примерами кода.

Смотрите, вам нужно различать var (ключевое слово неявного указания типа данных) и object (базовый тип).
var в любом случае будет каким-либо из типов (string, int и т. д.), просто вы переложите работу по определению типа на компилятор. Это затрудняет читаемость кода для других программистов (да и для вас самих).
Если вам нужно, чтобы user мог быть либо строкой, либо числом, то подойдёт следующее:
int? value = null;
object user = value == null ? "Не введено" : value;
Console.WriteLine(user.ToString());

Если вы всё же хотите использовать var (но я не рекомендую), то вот:
int? value = null;
var user = value == null ? "Не введено" : value.ToString(); // тут можно спокойно заменить `var` на `string?`, ведь этот код не гарантирует какое-либо значение для `string`
Console.WriteLine(user);

Если вы хотите, чтобы user точно был строкой, то вот подходящий код:
int? value = null;
string user = value == null ? "Не введено" : value.ToString() ?? "Не введено";
Console.WriteLine(user);

Тут дан хороший ответ про различия var и object: Разница между типами var и object в c#.


var - не тип, это ключевое слово, позволяющее компилятору самостоятельно выбрать тип. После компиляции, условный var value = 1; превратиться в int value = 1. 2. Пример с var ужасен. Вы теряете тип, а в некоторых случаях и данные. Вот что будет, если сделать допустим var value = new SomeClass();  someClass.ToString()? Будут там значения данного класса? Нет, там будет SomeNamespace.SomeClass - название типа, с которым вы ничего не сделаете.


Приведение объекта к типу object, приводит к boxing, что в свою очередь сказывается на производительности.
